# Natural logarithmic implication

Tags: sequences-and-series

Would you tell me how (how the second result is derived from the first one)  $ \ln\left(1+x\right) = \sum_{r=1}^\infty \left(-1    \right)^{r} \frac {x^{r}}{r} $ implies $\ln \left(\frac {1}{1-x}   \right)=\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{x^{r}}{r} $?

Comment: As you at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321743/natural-logarithmic-implication#comment2685511_1321752 and @MarcoCantarini at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321743/natural-logarithmic-implication#comment2685549_1321752 point out, your original series has a sign error; it should be $\ln(1 + x) = \sum_{r = 1}^\infty (-1)^{r + 1}x^r / r$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions).

Comment: You can see there's a sign error if you plug $x=1$ into your formula for $\ln(1+x)$.  Doing so gives $\ln2=-1+{1\over2}-{1\over3}+\cdots$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace $x$ by $-x$ to get

$$\log(1-x)=\sum_{r=1}^\infty(-1)^{r+1}\frac{(-1)^rx^r}{r}$$

And keep in mind that $(-1)^{2r}=1$

Comment: But would that not give that $ln \left(\frac {1}{1-x}   \right)=-\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{x^{r}}{r}$?

Comment: It is $$\log\left(1+x\right)=\sum_{r\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{r+1}x^{r}}{r}$$.